# How to restart a Fragment if it is paused?

Tags: android, android-fragments

My game doesn't make any sense to continue if it is paused, it can be used to cheat.

So if a phone call is received I want to restart the level. What is the best way to do this?

It seems wrong to make a fragment transaction onPause of the fragment. Should I do this in the Activity? Check if the current fragment is a GameFragment and if so make a transaction to a new GameFragment?

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in the activity. When onPause is called in your activity, it is called in the fragment as well (read up on fragment lifecycle).

Just log if a game has been started then in onResume check this boolean, if it has been started siimply rebind your fragment to the activity using fragment transaction.

You could also make it so your game could stop the call from pausing your game but that's a whole different thing entirely.